# Why does this bash "if" statement execute both statements

Tags: bash, if-statement, rsync

I am messing around with an rsync script to sync some stuff over to my phone.  I am trying to write an if statement that decides which message I get in an email upon the commands completion.  For some reason, I get both emails no matter how the command exits.

```
success_message=echo "Podcasts are synced." | mail -s "Your podcasts have been synced to   your phone." $email_address
fail_message=echo "Your phone did not sync." | mail -s "For some reason, your podcasts did not sync today." $email_address

rsync --log-file=/home/jake/logs/rsync.log -avzu $local_directory $remote_directory
if [ $? -ne "0" ];
then
  $fail_message
else
  $success_message
fi
```

Comment: Better fit on unix.stackexchange.com?

Comment: That's not how you conditionally run commands. At all.

Comment: Your `mail` commands are being executed even before you get to the `rsync`.

Answer (score 4):

This line

```
success_message=echo "Podcasts are synced." | mail ...
```

attempts to *execute a command named* "Podcasts are synced." (without the quotes, but with everything in between them), and pipe its output to the "mail" command.  The token "success_message=echo" causes an environment variable named "success_message" to be set in the environment of the "Podcasts are synced." command, with value "echo".

Critically, *even though* the thing on the left side of the pipe fails (because you don't have a program named `/usr/bin/Podcasts are synced.`, no doubt), the `mail` command on the right is executed.  And since there are two such lines, both commands run.

Here's how to do what you were trying to do:

```
send_success_message () {
    echo "Podcasts are synced." | 
        mail -s "Your podcasts have been synced to your phone." "$1"
}
send_fail_message () {
    echo "Your phone did not sync." |
        mail -s "For some reason, your podcasts did not sync today." "$1"
}

if rsync --log-file=/home/jake/logs/rsync.log -avzu \
         "$local_directory" "$remote_directory"
then send_success_message "$email_address"
else send_fail_message "$email_address"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

This line sends the message, because the first instruction ends at the pipe.

```
success_message=echo "Podcasts are synced." | mail -s "Your podcasts have been synced to   your phone." $email_address
```

Answer (score 1):

There's absolutely no benefit to try and put the commands into shell variables and then refer to the variables once each later. Just put the commands in the `if` statement:

```
rsync --log-file=/home/jake/logs/rsync.log -avzu $local_directory $remote_directory

if [ $? -ne "0" ];
then
    echo "Podcasts are synced." | mail -s "Your podcasts have been synced to   your phone." $email_address
else
    echo "Your phone did not sync." | mail -s "For some reason, your podcasts did not sync today." $email_address
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for all the replies.  I did just take the email lines out of variables which makes it work fine.  Thanks again.